# Question about Proof of First FTC

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

**First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**

$$f: [a.b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \implies F(x) = {\large \int_a^x}f(t)dt,\:\: \forall x \in (a,b) \:\: F'(x) = f(x)$$

---

**Proof of First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:**

for any $x_1, x_1+h \in [a,b]$ we have $$F(x_1) = {\large \int_a^{x_1}}f(t)dt,\:\:F({x_1+h}) = {\large \int_a^{x_1+h}}f(t)dt$$

$$F(x_1) - F({x_1+h}) = \int_{x_1}^{x_1+h}f(t)dt$$

by the [MVT for Definite Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

$$\exists c \in [x_1, x_1 + h] \:\: s.t  \:\: f(c) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{x_1}^{x_1+h}f(t)dt$$

which gives us

$$\lim_{h \to 0}f(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{x_1}^{x_1+h}f(t)d$$

since

$$x_1 \leq c \leq x_1 + h$$

by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

$$\lim_{h \to 0}x_1 = x_1, \:\: \lim_{h \to 0}[x_1+h] = x_1 \implies \lim_{h \to 0}c = x_1$$

and this is true for every $c$, therefore the Proof is completed.

---

**Questions**

in my knowledge the MVT for Definite Integral states in open interval and not closed interval
$$\exists c \in (x_1, x_1 + h) \:\: s.t  \:\: f(c) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{x_1}^{x_1+h}f(t)dt$$

so here are my question

- is the bound for this theorem $\forall x \in (a,b)$

if its true then that will make the Proof incorrect and if false that will make the MVT for Definite Integral False

and if everything above is false what is the correct proof and bound.

Comment: Your statement of the theorem is incorrect. The first part of the FTC requires $f$ continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean value theorem says that, under certain conditions, there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. But then, in particular, there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. There is no problem here.

Comment: what will that particular situation be, and how can I find that in the proof

Comment: also, does that mean the first fundamental theorem of calculus is true only in that particular. and if not, is it okay to prove this using $c \in (a,b)$ for more general proof

Comment: Concerning the “particular situation”, do you need a proof of the fact that, if there is a $c\in(a,b)$ with a certain property, then there is a $c\in[a,b]$ with that same property? You just take the **same** $c$ that worked before. Since that $c$ is in $(a,b)$, then, in particular, it is in $[a,b]$, which is a larger set than $(a,b)$.

Comment: okay, I'm thinking of that particular as a constant function f, and just to check my understanding, the reason why FCT doesn't say $\forall x \in [a,b]$ is when f is not a constant(or any other function that is "particular") right?

Comment: No. It's because the assertion $c\in(a,b)$ is stronger than $c\in[a,b]$. If you can prove a stronger assertion, why would we state the weaker one?